# Get information from wordpress post meta information based on 2 known fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I've given up on programing about 17 years ago, in the times before proper internet in my country. Now I can't afford a programer so i've taken up the task myself, yet my limited coding knowledge seems to have gotten me quite stuck..

**Situation:**

in wordpress, i have the folowing keys stored in the postmeta table for each post_id: *awb_urgent_cargus*, *_fgo_invoice_link*

**Problem:**

I need to create a shortcode that should display 2 input fields: [$post_id] and [$awb]. If the user enters a matching pair he gets the corresponding invoice link from the same $post_id.

Basicly after submiting,

if the corresponding *awb_urgent_cargus* key for the input [$post_id] is the value of input [$awb] then return the value for the key _fgo_invoice_link

else, return error

I found some documentation for this but i got stuck writing the code ... couldn't even get the inputs working :(
I think that swiching from ms-dos coding in c++ / pascal to the web is quite a bit over my head and while i managed to get around and modify examples for other stuff this one just simpli doesn't click

get_post_meta( int $post_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false );

Answer (score 0):

You could handle input with ajax, wordpress requires you to register allowed actions on backend, perform your check and return the result.

```
//js
var value = jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST', 
                url: ajaxurl,
                cache: false,
                data:{
                nonce : nonce,
                action: 'FUNCTIONNAME',
                },
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log(data.status);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){    
                    console.log('ajax error');
                }
            })

};
```

--

```
    //php    
    add_action('wp_ajax_FUNCTIONNAME', 'FUNCTIONNAME');
                
    function FUNCTIONNAME() {
    //your backend logic here
$data = array();
$data['status'] = 'all good';
echo json_encode($data);
die();
    }
```

Comment: I was just looking at ajax but i'm over my head. I literaly know what i need to do but can't write the code because I'm too out of date with the syntax.

Comment: it would be amazing if you could have pity on me and help me out with the syntax / code. I have been attepting to get a solution working for 11 hours and i'm at wits end :(

Answer (score 0):

You can put it all together like this.

```
function show_post_meta_value( $args ){

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'post_id' => '',
    ), $atts, 'show_post_meta_value' );

    if( $post_id != '' ){
        $awb_urgent_cargus = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'awb_urgent_cargus', true );
        $_fgo_invoice_link = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_fgo_invoice_link', true );

        return 'awb_urgent_cargus ==> '. $awb_urgent_cargus.' and _fgo_invoice_link ==> '.$_fgo_invoice_link;
    }

    return '';

}
add_shortcode( 'show_post_meta_value', 'show_post_meta_value' );
```

and use like this [show_post_meta_value post_id="yourpostidhere"]